# using ssl in wcf service

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I want to use SSL using security mode = transport.

Can I use it with following settings in my web config

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
           <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
           </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I am installing root certificate on server side and temp ceritficate on the client side. Should this work by current web settings??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if that's what you want to do:

- you'll have SSL-enabled HTTPS transport
- you're using the wsHttp binding
- your users will be authenticated against the Windows domain (Active Directory)

This requires that your client and server are in the same common Windows domain, or at least in two Windows domains that are in a mutual trust relationship with one another (so that the service can authenticate the calling user against Active Directory).

This will **not** support anonymous callers, or callers from outside your Windows domain.

The question is: if it's really within your Windows domain and thus behind your corporate firewall, why are you using wsHttpBinding?  NetTcpBinding would be much faster and more efficient in this scenario....

Marc

Comment: Thanks Marc, Just a last question. To enable SSL support I am creating Root certificate that is deployed on server Trusted domain and Temp Certificate that is deployed on client machine. Is that the right approach ?

Comment: @Ashish: I must admit, I'm not intimately familiar with the details of how to set up SSL on client and server, quite honestly.

Comment: This is intranet scenario and client and service are in same domain

Comment: No issues Marc. I just want to verify that using 
<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" /> I can use SSL-Enable approach (Certificates ).

Comment: @Asish: yes, the securityMode=transport requires some type of transport-level security, which is typically handled by using SSL.